# Gauss Law: Electric Flux and relation with Charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

What does the Gauss law specifically say? I know that $$\text{Electric Flux}=\frac{\text{Total Charge contained}}{\epsilon}$$

But while reading on the method of curvilinear square, there is a line:

> The total charge contained by the conductor is equal tothe  flux emanating from it.

Which is true? Or how are they different but both still right?

Comment: What is the problem? The absence of the dielectric constant? If that is the case, it's just a matter of units of measure.

Comment: @Aditya SURESH As Feynman_00 has already asked, what do you think is the difference between the two statements? One talks about total charge and the other electric flux, but both statements are identical, less a constant.

Comment: Is your source using units where $\epsilon=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a question of units.

Gauss' law in SI units is as you have written it. In SI units, $\epsilon_0=8.8542\times 10^{-12} F m^{-1}$. In cgs & Gaussian units, $\epsilon_0=1$, and is unitless. Your source is probably using one of the latter systems.